# How do I access the full path of a request in Akka HTTP request?

Tags: scala, akka-http

In some contexts I can match on the remaining path using a PathDirective to get the information I need about the path.  For example, when `route` below is directly bound and handled by Akka HTTP, every request will echo back the requested path as desired.

```
val route =
  path(Remaining) { path =>
    complete(path)
  }
```

However, when the above route is combined elsewhere in the application, the `path` variable above may only hold part of the requested path not giving the desired results.

For example if the actual bound route is be,

```
val actualRoute = pathPrefix("echo") { route }
```

The "echo/" part of the overall path will be missing from the response given to the user.

How can the complete path be reliably accessed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Directives `extractMatchedPath` and `extractUnmatchedPath`](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/scala/http/routing-dsl/directives/basic-directives/index.html#providing-values-to-inner-routes) let you access the path without matching the path like you `path` directive does above.  These two can be combined to construct the full path:

```
val route =
  extractMatchedPath { matched =>
    extractUnmatchedPath { unmatched =>
      complete((matched.dropChars(1) ++ unmatched).toString)
    }
  }
```

However it is probably cleaner just to extract the `Path` from the URI directly:

```
val route =
  extractUri { uri =>
    complete(uri.toRelative.path.dropChars(1).toString)
  }
```

Note that in both cases we needed to call `.dropChars(1)` to drop the initial forward slash and be consistent with the output you got using the `path` directive.